# Почему после первого заполнения структуры всё прерывается и выводит какой-то бред

Tags: c++

объясните пожалуйста, почему после первого заполнения структуры, а именно после ввода Name Of Book всё прерывается и выводит какой-то бред.

```
 #include <clocale>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;
struct book
{
char title[50];
char authors[50];
char publisher[25];
int year;
unsigned int pages;
};
const int N = 3;
book collection[N]; // создаем массив из N структур book
int main()
{
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");


for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
 {
            printf("\n\nEnter data for the book №%d\n", i + 1);
            printf(" Name Of Book - ");
            
      scanf("%79[^\n]", collection[i].title);   
            SetConsoleCP(866);
            printf(" Author - ");
            SetConsoleCP(1251);
             scanf("%79[^\n]", collection[i].authors); 
            SetConsoleCP(866);
            printf(" Publisher - ");
            SetConsoleCP(1251);


             scanf("%79[^\n]", collection[i].publisher); 
            SetConsoleCP(866);
 
 }


char find_title[50];
 printf("\n\n Enter the title of the book you are looking for - ");
 SetConsoleCP(1251);
   scanf("%79[^\n]", find_title); 
 SetConsoleCP(866);
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
 {
 if (strcmp(collection[i].title, find_title) == 0)
 {
 found = true;
 printf("\n======== FOUND BOOK ==========\n");
 printf(" Name: ");
 puts(collection[i].title);
 printf(" Authors ");
 puts(collection[i].authors);
 printf(" Publisher: ");
 puts(collection[i].publisher);
 printf(" Year of issue: %d\n", collection[i].year);
 printf(" Pages %u\n", collection[i].pages);
 }
 }
if (!found)
 printf(" A book with this title was not found in the collection.!\n");
 system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Бред:

Enter data for the book в"-1
Name Of Book - fekekef
Author -  Publisher -

Enter data for the book в"-2
Name Of Book -  Author -  Publisher -

Enter data for the book в"-3
Name Of Book -  Author -  Publisher -

Enter the title of the book you are looking for -
======== FOUND BOOK ==========
Name:
Authors
Publisher:
Year of issue: 0
Pages 0

Comment: может плохо объяснил, когда ввожу название книги, после ввода выдаются остальные поля сразу все, без их нужного заполнения

Answer (score 3):

Вам некуда деть `\n` в буфере ввода — его никто не принимает. Напишите так, например:

```
    scanf("\n%79[^\n]", collection[i].title);
    printf(" Author - ");
    scanf("\n%79[^\n]", collection[i].authors);
    printf(" Publisher - ");
    scanf("\n%79[^\n]", collection[i].publisher);
```

Только вот длины буферов у вас 50, 50 и 25, а вы им всем позволяете читать по 79 символов. Нехорошо...

Answer (score 0):

0. Писать `scanf` / `printf` и при этом использовать плюсовый компилятор - как минимум дурной тон. Если пишете на `C++`, пользуйтесь `C++` (`cin`, `cout`)
1. Ваша проблема в том, что у вас в форматной строке у `scanf` нету `\n`. Так что символ перевода строки остается в буфере, от чего весь последующий ввод оказывается поломан.